# In Ruby on Rails, summarizing data from a file before saving to a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a conceptual question; I am trying to write code to download logs from s3 and then parse and store some of that data in a database within a rails application.

Since this is strictly internal, I only have a model that has the necessary code to download and parse the logs. My main method for parsing opens a file, iterates through each line parsing out certain pieces of data I want to save to the database.

My goal is to summarize all of the data from a file (which has several logs in it) and then save it to the database.

What I am struggling to grasp is how would I go about summarizing data before I save it to the database within Rails?

For instance if I have the following logs:

log/account/6 100
log/account/7 250
log/account/6 50
log/account/5 100

My goal would be to iterate through all the lines and save the aggregate amount for each account ID, so in this cause I would want to save for account 6, 150 as the sum. For some reason I can only understand 1 database entry for 1 log instead of summarizing the logs from a file and turning it into 1 database entry.

Current parse process:

```
   def self.create_from_log_file(file)
    s3log = File.open(file).each do |line|
    line_match = S3_LINE_REGEXP.match(line)# get the matchdata
    captures = Hash[ line_match.names.zip( line_match.captures ) ]# convert the matchdata to a hash key value pairs (both strings)
    validate_log_file(captures["timestamp"])# validate file is unique
    captures["http_status"] != 200 # figure out if API request was a http 200
    current_account = extract_account_id(captures["request_path"])# extract account id and find that account
    account_log = S3Log.new # instantiate a new S3Log instance
    account_log.account_id = Account.find_by_id(current_account) # assign the S3Log object its account id
    account_log.total_bytes = calculate_total_bytes_for_file(captures["bytes_sent"])# assign the log bytes to that accounts total for the file
    account_log.total_requests = calculate_total_requests_for_file(acount_log.account_id)# calculate total requests for that account on the file
    account_log.date = Date.parse(captures["timestamp"])
  end

  account_log.save!
end
```

Comment: You should be using a controller, and then you can print out your objects data before you call `save` on that model object.

Answer (score 0):

A few high level pointers. First, since your code might be a longish running job, it might be worth running it as a background job using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Second, break your work into small well defined functions and then write tests for those smaller functions. You will then have the confidence to combine them into the larger piece, i.e practice functional decomposition. Or, go the OO way, and create models to encapsulate the parsing logic, another one to represent lines of interest and probably a third to represent a collection of lines on which you can perform the aggregation methods.

Hope this helps.